# Python: Does any one knows the Received mail date Parameter for msg Outlook file?

Tags: python, email, outlook, msg

I am working to parse the msg (Outlook mail) file using python. I found number of attributes shown in to the code that I did so far,

I did following code for that,

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")
print msg.SenderName
print msg.SenderEmailAddress
print msg.SentOn
print msg.To
print msg.CC
print msg.BCC
print msg.Subject
print msg.Body
```

I would like to have Received data intead of SendOn date. Does any one knows, which attribute I have to use instead of msg.SendOn?

Comment: It's **ReceivedTime**. The docs are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx).

Comment: Thanks It works :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `MailItem.ReceivedTime` property.